# Gmail like registration layout in Android

Tags: android, xml, layout

I often put user registration on one xml file with scroll view.

I have learned when a user sees too many fields they opt out of the app so I am planning to upgrade the layout to look like the one for gmail when you sign up on android app. It appears to be using tabbed view but not tabs available and user navigates to the next view by clicking next (refer to attached images).

First page

[image]

second page

[image]

**MY QUESTION**
My question is how do I create this views, do I need many xml layout files or put all stuff on one file and use visibility as in once it is filled and user presses next hide the inputs and reveal the next inputs. Note: Gmail appears to be scrolling to another page the way it would appear when using tabs.

Comment: Use View Pager and Fragments.

Comment: Many ways to do this like ViewPager and Fragments. Choose what suits your need best.

Comment: Thank you I will try View Pager... Yes my app is based on fragments because it is easy for screen sizes

Answer (score 0):

You can use one activity to host multiple fragments. The new Android Studio update has [Navigation Editor](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/navigation/navigation-implementing) which you can use to achieve similar results.

Comment: Thank you, I will research into it including compatibility with earlier versions of Android. Thank you for pointing me towards some direction

Answer (score 0):

it is totally up to you how you want to design this but the best thing is you use `Fragment` and `viewpager`  instead of using two separate layouts.
[See Here how to use fragment with viewpager](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/ViewPager-with-FragmentPagerAdapter)

Comment: I do not like to have the page tabs so I think I will try Navigation Editor or ViewFlipper as suggested by other contributors. Thank you for your contribution sir

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this, If you have less content then play with visibility otherwise ViewFipper ( https://abhiandroid.com/ui/viewflipper )  Or can use [Fragments](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidFragments/article.html)

Comment: I appreciate your help sir, yes I liked view flipper example you redirected me to, I have lot's of content that is why I mentioned that users get bored at a glance. I will try your suggestion.

Comment: if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself.